# Need proof/breakdown of String.hashCode() method in java

Tags: java, hashcode

I know that the formula adopted for the String.hashCode() method is as follows:

```
S0x31(n-1)+s1x31(n-2)+…+s(n-1)
```

In my textbook, I am given the example of the word Cat.

```
'C'  x31^2 + 'a' x 31 +t
```

The final value is given as `67,510`

I am utterly confused as to where this value was derived from, specifically, what values were used for the individual characters. I have tried 37, 66 and 85 (utilising the Unicode character for capital C, lower case a and t respectively). This was invalid. Can someone illumninate this for me?

Regrettably, this is the only example given by my textbook and there is no attempt to clarify or explain it.

Comment: Where exactly did you get those values from? 37, 66 and 85 that is? If you look at [ASCII table](https://www.ascii-code.com/), values are 67, 97 and 116 respectively. Seems about right to me.

Comment: Decimal values, I've interpeted the table wrongly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
67 * 31^2 + 97 * 31^1 + 116 * 31^0 = 
67 * 31^2 + 97 * 31 + 116 = 
64387 + 3007 + 116 = 
67510
```

With 67, 97 and 116 taken from http://www.asciitable.com/

Answer (score 0):

String hashCode does:

```
public int hashCode() {
    int h = hash;
    if (h == 0 && value.length > 0) {
        char val[] = value;

        for (int i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
            h = 31 * h + val[i];
        }
        hash = h;
    }
    return h;
}
```

So basically each iteration the existing hash is multiplied by 31, and then the next value is added to the hash.

so with 'C' = 67, 'a' = 97, 't' = 116 you get:

```
h = 0
h *= 31;
h += 67; // 'C'   

h *= 31;
h += 97; // 'a'

h *= 31;
h += 116;

h ==> 67510
```